# SharePoint 2013 FBA Pack without SQL server Management Studio

Tags: sharepoint-server, forms-authentication, sql-server

I used of "prerequisites installation" option for install all of prerequisites for SharePoint 2013. This option just installed SQL server 2008 R2 without SQL server Management Studio. After SharePoint configuration and site creation, I understood that I need to a web part for user password management. I found [this](http://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/) that seems very good, but when I wanted to install it, I saw that I need to SQL Server Management Studio for aspnet.db management.
I don't know what to do.

Do I install SQL Server Management Studio? 2008 version or 2012?

Is there any way to do that without SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Having Management Studio in the environment is not a bad thing at all, rather it will be good while monitoring your SharePoint farm/Dbs.

- If your SQL server version is 2008R2, then SSMS 2008 version will be
  fine(as i am using)
- But if your SQL server version if 2012 then you need SSMS 2013 version.it will work with old versions as well.

As per the Codeplex installation guide you have to set the DB permission before installing the FBA pack, if you dont have the SSMS then you can run the SQL Powershell on the SQL server and set the permission.

```
$SQLAdminUser = 'AdminUser'
$SQLAdminPwd = get-content "PathToSecuredCredentials.txt" | convertto-securestring

$srvConn = New-Object('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection') ('ServerName', $SQLAdminUser, $SQLAdminPwd)
$srv = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $srvConn

$srv.Databases | where{$_.Name -eq 'DatabaseName'} | 
foreach {
    $_.SetOwner('sa')
    $_.Alter();
}
```

http://sqlserverpowershell.com/2012/04/17/set-database-owner-using-powershell/

helpfull link: http://sqlmag.com/powershell/powershell-sql-server-way

Comment: I wanted to use your instruction, but when I execute aspnet_regsql for producing aspnet.db I got the error message: 
Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to SQL Server database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections....

Comment: looks like sql connection error, make sure sql server up and running...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26282021/exception-unable-to-connect-to-sql-server-database